# `get_posts()` ignore my custom post

Tags: get-posts

I have a Custom Post Type:

```
function thfo_register_cantine() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Cantines',
        'singular_name'      => 'Cantine',
        'menu_name'          => 'Cantine',
        'all_items'          => 'Tous les Menus',
        'add_new'            => 'Ajouter un menu',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Ajouter un menu',
        'edit'               => 'Modifier',
        'edit_item'          => 'Modifier le menu',
        'new_item'           => 'Nouveau menu',
        'view'               => 'Voir',
        'view_item'          => 'Voir le menu',
        'search_items'       => 'Chercher un menu',
        'not_found'          => 'Rien de trouver',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Non trouvé dans la corbeille',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'description'         => '',
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap'        => true,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'cantine', 'with_front' => true ),
        'query_var'           => true,
        'supports'            => array( 'title' ),
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_admin_menu'  => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'cantine', $args );
}
```

On `front-page.php`,  If I ask

`get_posts( array('post_type'     => array( 'cantine' ),'posts_per_page' => 2,));`

I have my 2 posts but if I ask
`get_posts( array( 'post__in' => $ids, 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );`
Where `$ids` is an array with my CPT ids, then, I haven't any results ...

Do you have any ideas why ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we do not specify post types, WordPress searches only 'posts'

```
$actus_new = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'      => array( 'cantine', 'post' ),
    'post__in'       => $ids,
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
) );
```